# how to make a form field exact?

Tags: django, django-forms

In django how to make form field exact, i.e it will have choices?

My forms.py:

```
from django import forms


class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    category = forms.CharField()
    price = forms.IntegerField()
```

My models.py:

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('Fruits and Vegetables', 'Fruits and Vegetables'),
        ('Electronics', 'Electronics'),
        ('Clothing', 'Clothing'),
        ('Books', 'Books'),
    )


class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.FloatField()
    discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2083, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "exact"?

Comment: It will have choices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make use of a [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/). A `ModelForm` is capable of automating a lot of aspects when creating or update model records. Furthermore it can automatically construct the fields based on the fields of the model. You can, if you want to, alter the widgets, etc. But usually a `ModeLField` is a good starting point.

Here you thus can construct a form like:

```
# app/forms.py

from django import forms
from app.models import Item

class FilterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['category', 'price']
```

Where you replace *`app`* with the name of the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ModelForm

```
from django import forms
from .models import Item

class FilterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = [
            'category',
            'price'
        ]
```

If you wanna stick with Form, use Choice Field and copy the Choices in form

```
from django import forms


class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('Fruits and Vegetables', 'Fruits and Vegetables'),
        ('Electronics', 'Electronics'),
        ('Clothing', 'Clothing'),
        ('Books', 'Books'),
    )
    category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    price = forms.IntegerField()
```